# How to pass a variable within the API url in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, react-native

I am building a search bar in my application and want the URL to be modified according to the user input. 
The user's input is a name i.e : *'John'*. in this function below I have added a name manually for testing.

How can I make it in a way that this function takes a variable to be inserted within the URL instead of 'John', to take the user's input from the `TextInput`

`search` function :

```
 search(){
    return fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/v0.0.5/search_user?q=John')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
    isLoading: false,
    userInfo: responseJson,
    });
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
    console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Text input :

```
<TextInput style = {styles.input} placeholder="Search for users" onChangeText={this.handleSearch} 
value={??}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the name from state, assuming that handleSearch save the value as `this.setState({ name: value})`, add the value to url using template strings.

```
search = () => {
  return fetch(`http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/v0.0.5/search_user?q=${this.state.name}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        userInfo: responseJson,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

The value for input would be the one from state, being set in handleSearch.

```
<TextInput style = {styles.input} placeholder="Search for users" onChangeText{this.handleSearch} value={this.state.name}/>

handleSearch = (value) => {

 this.setState({ name: value}, this.search)
}
```